# IHostBuilder configuration cannot load xml files

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, .net-5

I have a co-worker who have a problem with posting here, he will be the one answering comments and validating answer. Here is his question:

I'm using Net5 with Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting. Instead of appsettings.json, I need to use xml files. I have App.config to specify common app settings (log4net config, etc.) and AcquisitionManagerConfiguration.xml for the settings on each installation (hardware stuff).

I went like this :
Program.cs

```
public class Program
    {
        public static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            CreateHostBuilder(args).Build().Run();
        }

        public static IHostBuilder CreateHostBuilder(string[] args)
        {
            IHostBuilder ihb = Host.CreateDefaultBuilder(args);
            ihb.ConfigureAppConfiguration((hostingContext, configuration) =>
            {
                
                //configuration.Sources.Clear();
                configuration.SetBasePath(AppContext.BaseDirectory);
                configuration.AddXmlFile("AcquisitionManagerConfiguration.xml", optional: false, reloadOnChange: true)
                   .AddXmlFile("App.config", optional: false, reloadOnChange: true);

                configuration.AddEnvironmentVariables();

            }).ConfigureServices((hostingContext, services) =>
            {
               
                services.AddHttpClient();               
                services.Configure<AcquisitionManagerConfiguration>(hostingContext.Configuration.GetSection("AcquisitionManagerConfiguration"));
                services.AddTransient<AcquisitionManager.AcquisitionManager>();
                services.AddTransient<IServiceClient, ServiceClient>();
                services.AddHostedService<Worker>();
            });
            return ihb;
        }
    }
```

AcquisitionManager.cs

```
public AcquisitionManager(IServiceClient serviceClient, IOptions<AcquisitionManagerConfiguration> config)
{
client = serviceClient;
configuration = config.Value;
}
```

and the first xml

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
    <AcquisitionManagerConfiguration>
        <val>1</val>
    </AcquisitionManagerConfiguration>
```

AcquisitionManagerConfiguration.cs matches exactly the xml, it worked fine if I manually deserialize.

But using the hosting system, I never have anything in config.Value.

Any idea what I'm doing wrong ?
I didn't find the solution so I posted here.
Thanks for the help.

Comment: There's not part in the code which says that val1 should be mapped to Value. In the config file you can put anything: val1, val69, val_1, val-giraffes, val-val, mayonaisse-shrimps, bubba-likes--shrimps or literally anything. In some part of the code, must exists a single line to tell the compiler from where to extract the single value. The code is telling how to read AcquisitionManagerConfiguration, but not how to reach val1

Comment: On a side note, there's a syntas error here: <val1>1</val>

Comment: thank you, I have edited the question to remove the "1" from "val1"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem come from the xml structure:

As this is application configuration the structure from this:

```xml
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
    <AcquisitionManagerConfiguration>
        <val>1</val>
    </AcquisitionManagerConfiguration>
```

become this:

```xml
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
    <Configuration>
        <AcquisitionManagerConfiguration>
            <val>1</val>
        </AcquisitionManagerConfiguration>
    </Configuration>
```

Comment: Hmmm... not really. He's trying to read the value inside Val1, but he is reading something called "Value". Also, there's an error here: <val1>1</val>: opening and closing tag mismatch

Comment: My bad for the tag mismatch, but this is just a sample, there is no such problem in our xml. Not sure what you mean by "he is reading something called "Value"". If you mean reading "Value" in AcquisitionManager constructor, no he isn't: He is reading the value of IOption which is an object AcquisitionManagerConfiguration

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are just missing the `Bind` part in your services registration.

`services.Configure<AcquisitionManagerConfiguration>(options => Configuration.GetSection("AcquisitionManagerConfiguration"));`

should be

`services.Configure<AcquisitionManagerConfiguration>(options => Configuration.GetSection("AcquisitionManagerConfiguration").Bind(options));`

Comment: He tried with the bind methods, but nothing changed, still have the object but all value are null or default in AcquisitionManager.